# В docker контейнере криво отображается mc и nano, в чем дело?

Tags: linux, docker, ui

Внутри docker контейнера открываю `mc`. Сначала все хорошо. А если просмотреть файл какой-то на F3, то получится такая лажа:

[image: Кривое отображение mc на F3]

После `mc` выглядит так:
[image: Кривое отображение mc]

Если использовать `nano` и двигать вверх-вниз курсор, текст начинает перемешиваться:
[image: Кривое отображение nano]

Криво отображает как и в ZOC7 Terminal, так и в PuTTy.
Вне docker'a нет багов в обрисовке терминала.

Comment: добавте какой образ в использовании. это проблема не самого докера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это было из-за tmux'a, лучше не запускать mc внутри docker'a, который открыт в tmux'e.